# Custom URL rules with modules in Yii2

Tags: php, url-routing, yii2

I have been looking around but haven't found what I needed. Basically, I have a few small modules which have just the DefaultController and a few bigger ones with multiple controllers.
My rules for the small modules work fine but the ones of the big modules won't. Here are my rules:

```
'<module:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/default/<action>',
'<module:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/default/<action>',
'<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/index',
'<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>'
```

The first two rules work fine, allowing me to access:
`http://host/news/create` and routes to `news/default/create`.

The last two are supposed to do the following:
`http://host/posts/category` which should route to `posts/category/index`
and
`http://host/posts/category/create` which should route to `posts/category/create`

They do not seem to work, sadly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the first rule will capture any request that could also match the third one.

Think of it in the terms of its representing regex: `w+/w+`: as a generic rule for routes in Yii, more prescriptive rules should go on top and less more generic, catch-all rules should be at the bottom.

Now the best way to obtain what you need would be to do something along the lines of:

```
'<module:news>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/default/<action>',
'<module:news>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/default/<action>',
'<module:posts>/<controller:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/index',
'<module:posts>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>'
```

this way you are explicitly expressing the routes for each of the modules in a clear and immediate way which will also help you in the long-term.

Comment: Wouldn't this eventually end up with a huge list of rules? Or is there a way to add multiple modules to a single rule?

Comment: Ideally yes, but it really depends on a case by case basis. In this situation the first two "default" ones might be the specific rule for any module, but that you need to ensure all the modules have a generic structure and would respond to that query correctly. Secondly this is an architecture problem rather than anything else: by making two rules that respond to `w+/w+` you're creating a conflict of routes, where the first take precedence, hence the need to differentiate. You can aggregate multiple modules in the same rule in the following way: `<module:(posts|otherModule)>/<controller:\w+>`.