# Cant resolve site/index after splitting in two "modules"

Tags: php, yii2

I wanted to split manager and frontend:

**root/manager/controllers/SiteController.php**

```
namespace manager\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;

class SiteController extends Controller
{

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        echo 'hallo';
        //return $this->render('index');
    }
}
```

**root/manager/config/web.php**

```
$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'manager\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [
        'manager' => [
            'class' => 'manager\Module',
        ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'X',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '' => 'site/index',
                'fragebogen/erstellung/<id>' => 'questionary/creation',
                'fragebogen/erstellung' => 'questionary/creation',
                'auftraege-importieren' => 'upload/jobs',
                'auftraege-erfolgreich-importiert' => 'upload/jobssuccess',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = 'yii\gii\Module';
}

return $config;
```

**root/manager/web/index.php**

```
<?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

And i get this error:

```
exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "site/error".' in /kunden/xxx/xxx/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php:461 Stack trace:
#0 /kunden/xxx/xxx/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(80): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/error')
#1 /kunden/xxx/xxx/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(95): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#3 {main} Previous exception: exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "site/index".' in /kunden/xxx/xxx/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php:461 Stack trace:
#0 /kunden/xxx/xxx/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(83): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/index', Array)
#1 /kunden/xxx/xxx/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#2 /kunden/xxx/xxx/manager/web/index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#3 {main}

Next exception 'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "site/index".' in /kunden/xxx/xxx/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php:95 Stack trace:
#0 /kunden/xxx/xxx/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#1 /kunden/xxx/xxx/manager/web/index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#2 {main}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use this https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced? It is already split up for you. You are trying to change the basic template to make it like the advanced template.

Comment: I could use it but i want to use my own namespaces and maybe use more than two modules.

Comment: Please show the whole folder structure, what's the root folder of frontend and manager folders. It's called root?

Comment: And I also don't get what you want to achieve. Split in modules or applications? You mentioned modules but it looks like applications.

Comment: The root folder isn't called root.. i only wrote root for your information.. on the screenshot you see the whole file structure...

Comment: I have one application.. and different types of access.. a "manager" for our employees to manage customer jobs etc.. a frontend for a website which accesses the database too.. this "modules" or "applications" are using the same models but have differnt layouts and controllers etc.. are modules the correct way? its the first time i hear something about applications..

Comment: in the advanced yii package there are no index.php files in web directory - i dont understand that.. otherwise i would use this.. are they using apps or modules there?

Comment: There are two common approaches for this: advanced application - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced and separation via modules - https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/structure-backend-frontend-modules.md. For what you described I think advanced application will be enough. As for you last question, entry scripts are located in specific applications (frontend and backend), common folder is for shared code. Initially they are not exist until you execute console command `init`. https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/init

Comment: I can understand the module approach u are trying to use here. I use it for many of the projects. Here are few things I find as incorrect. 1. The modules in basic template don't have a separate config folder. They share the config under root/config/web.php. 2. I would suggest you to create the module via gii so that u can get the proper folder structure. 3. To access the module, use http://<websitename>.com/manager. 
Let me know if i'm wrong or u need further help

Comment: have you updated the common/config/bootstrap.php and added the new alias "manager" ?

Answer (score 4):

is this topic resolved?
If not, check your bootstrap file in common/config/bootstrap.php. 
If your application is trying to use a path alias and it can't be resolved you will get the following exception!

*exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "site/error".*

**Example**
wrong path is
*Yii::setAlias('backend', dirname(dirname(**DIR**)) . 'backend');*
correct path is
*Yii::setAlias('backend', dirname(dirname(**DIR**)) . '/backend');*

Comment: i set this.. but still i am getting that error.. `Unable to resolve the request "site/error`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the url rules, you might have to define the default rule to include the module name of at least. See this [Custom URL rules with modules in Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402923/custom-url-rules-with-modules-in-yii2)

**EDIT**
Take a look at my installations instructions for my module https://github.com/Mihai-P/yii2-core

In short, not sure what controllerNamespace does there, you should remove it. I do something similar here: https://github.com/Mihai-P/yii2-core/blob/master/Module.php

Afterwards this

> 'class' => 'manager\Module'

I do not think that will work, where is the manager namespace? How would Yii know to look for it? I use composer to add the namespace in the autoloader, you should probably do something like that manually. Tell Yii that manager means your manager folder, afterwards it will find the controllers.

Also this might help, creating an alias to that folder https://github.com/Mihai-P/yii2-core#note-2

Comment: Removing the url rules didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I think controllerNamespace may be deprectated in Yii2?

Can you replace that in your config, and use a controllerMap?

```
'controllerMap' => [
    'site' => 'manager\controllers\SiteController',
],
```

Comment: It definitely available in Yii2 and should be set in the scenario from the OP.
See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#controllernamespace

Answer (score 0):

There are some config settings which look questionable to me, first

```
'modules' => [
    'manager' => [
        'class' => 'manager\Module',
    ],
],
```

Since you've created a separate app, you should remove this setting. From your screenshot there
are also no modules in the manager application.

For debugging, just set `enablePrettyUrl` URL to `false` and reeable it after it is working without
nice URLs.

You may also need set an alias in `bootstrap.php` for `manager`, not sure about that, but worth a try.

From your error message I'd say that the application is not able to load the `SiteController` at all,
because `site/error` fails also.

*Addon: Personally, I'd recommend just one app per project, but I know that this a controversial topic.
It just looked to me, like you had that and were switching to two apps for some reason. **If** you just want to 
apply a custom theme to your manager, you could easily do that by [module configuration](https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/1d97ddf85af581abef252bd631c49d344375eb99/config/main.php#L58) 
...*

Answer (score 0):

I guess you dont have an alias to your application folder. Maybe autoloading component cannot find your controller file. You can add an alias in your config file doing:

```
\Yii::setAlias(’@manager’, dirname(__FILE__).'/..');
```

But I think the best way is to create another module for manager instead of dividing into different namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed that this error generally occurs due to mis-configuration or due to case sensitive names of classes and namespaces. In my case the error was due to the configuration of ii8n component. I was using the following configuration

```
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            '*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@backend/messages',
                'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
                'forceTranslation'=> true,
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

The issue was resolved after I removed the configuration

Answer (score 0):

I guess you dont have an alias to manager folder.

add an alias in your `common\config\bootstrap.php`.

```
Yii::setAlias('@manager', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/manager');
```

so your `common\config\bootstrap.php` file should look like:

```
Yii::setAlias('@common', dirname(__DIR__));
Yii::setAlias('@frontend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend');
Yii::setAlias('@backend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/backend');
Yii::setAlias('@console', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/console');
Yii::setAlias('@manager', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/manager');
```