# How to create custom rule for friendly url to module in Yii 2

Tags: module, routes, yii2, friendly-url

I have module in the frontend, and I want to make a friendly url like:

```
//yourdomain/a-zA-Z_module-controller-action-id-page-1.html
```

such as like this link:

```
http://kudufood.com/com-van-phong-lam-the-nao-de-nau-canh-bong-cai-duoc-ngon-kudu_cookbooks_1429067720.html
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable pretty URLs by adding the following code to your application components in config/web.php and configure custom URLs in 'rules':

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName'=>true,
        'rules' => [
            // your rules go here
            'customURL'=>'my-controller/my-action'
        ],
```

---

If you wish to hide index.php as well, then set:

```
 'showScriptName'=>false
```

and create an *.htaccess* file your /web directory with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html

Comment: My problem is not make a friendly url in the controller. I want to make a friendly on the module. And an other thing is: I do not want to have the forward slash "/" . I would like to be like this: h.t.t.p://yourdomain/a-zA-Z_module-controller-action-id-page-1.html

Comment: You are looking for something like this maybe:
'<module:news>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/default/<action>',
'<module:news>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/default/<action>',
'<module:posts>/<controller:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/index',
'<module:posts>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>'

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402923/custom-url-rules-with-modules-in-yii2